# How can I set the billing_cycle_anchor when setting up a subscription using a Checkout Session?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

As the title says: where can I set the billing_cycle_anchor when setting up a subscription using a Checkout Session? It's clear how this is done when setting up a subscription using the subscription API ( https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create
); however, I cannot find any details about how to set the billing_cycle_anchor in a Checkout Session ( https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create
). Does anyone know how I can do this (I'm using node.js)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

billing_cycle_anchor isn't supported by Checkout when creating Subscriptions at this time. Another option would be to set the Subscription to trial for a period which would start the billing cycle at the end of the trial:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-trial_end

Comment: But then you can't define any proration behaviour, right? I want the billing cycle for my users to start on the first of the coming month; however, I still want them to pay for the rest of the month they sign up

Comment: That's right, the subscription data object on the checkout session doesn't support proration to date: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node#create_checkout_session-subscription_data

Comment: Yeah okay, thanks @v3nkman, seems like a pretty big shortcoming for checkout session though

Comment: If you decide to go this route, you should be warned that trial_end and trial_period_days both require it to be at least 48 hours out. If you are in the last day of the month when using either option, it will give the user 2 days of trial.

Comment: Yeah its a shame the checkout dont support it, it should have an open field to include any parameters that we can pass to the POST subscriptions route

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now available (since 26 April, 2023). [See docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-billing_cycle_anchor).

You can set the anchor while creating the checkout session like this:

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: 'subscription',
    subscription_data: {
        billing_cycle_anchor: 1682985600
    },
    // other data ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by @xyres, feature is available now, but you cannot mix it with any trial setting at checkout.

```
raw: {
    message: 'You may only specify one of these parameters: billing_cycle_anchor, trial_end.',
    param: 'subscription_data[billing_cycle_anchor]',
...
```

I'm facing the same scenario and I will try something different: using checkout with "setup" mode, and then define a subscription to this client.

I will update here if it works.

Comment: Were you able to make it work? Can you share your updated work to use "setup" mode and then creating a subscription for the customer? Thanks

Comment: Hi @OmerIftikhar, this should help you: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials#combine-trial-anchor

But you have to save customer's payment info (aka. credit card) before you send subscription request. Or, in other words: there is not possible to use stripe checkout.
Our decision: still using stripe checkout, provide 7-day trial and forget about an equal billing cycle for all customers.